# improper, flat priors in pymc3

Tags: bayesian, pymc3, stan

I am "translating" selected models from the ARM book from Stan to pymc3 
(I hope to post them on  Github soon) and I have a question on "improper priors".

I understand that Stan default is to use uniform priors on parameters. If unbounded this means **uniform(-inf, +inf)**

My question is : **Is there anyway to specify such priors in pymc3?**

Here is an example to illustrate the problem and what I have tried so far.

```
import numpy as np
import pymc3 as pm

light_speed <-  np.array(28, 26, 33, 24, 34, -44, 27, 16, 40, -2, 29, 22, 24, 21, 25, 
30, 23, 29, 31, 19, 24, 20, 36, 32, 36, 28, 25, 21, 28, 29, 
37, 25, 28, 26, 30, 32, 36, 26, 30, 22, 36, 23, 27, 27, 28, 
27, 31, 27, 26, 33, 26, 32, 32, 24, 39, 28, 24, 25, 32, 25, 
29, 27, 28, 29, 16, 23)
```

#### In stan (pystan)

```
 #the model in pystan as specified in stan arm examples

model_string = '''
data {
  int<lower=0> N; 
  vector[N] y;
 }
parameters {
vector[1] beta;
real<lower=0> sigma;
} 
model {
 y ~ normal(beta[1],sigma);
}
'''
# Stan object 
StanDSO = ps.StanModel(model_code = model_string)

# data 
 data = dict(N = len(light_speed),
        y = light_speed
       )

#fit and verify model results 
fit_model = StanDSO.sampling(data=data, iter = 5000, chains = 2, thin = 1)
print fit_model
```

#### in pymc3

```
model_1= pm.Model()

with model_1:
    #priors as specified in stan model 
    mu = pm.Uniform('mu', lower = -np.inf, upper= np.inf)
    sigma = pm.Uniform('sigma', lower = 0, upper= np.inf)


    #using vague priors works 
    #mu = pm.Uniform('mu', lower = light_speed.std()/1000.0, upper= light_speed.std()*1000.0)
    #sigma = pm.Uniform('sigma', lower = light_speed.std()/1000.0, upper= light_speed.std()*1000.0)

    # define likelihood
    y_obs = pm.Normal('Y_obs', mu = mu, sd = sigma, observed = light_speed)

    # inference fitting the model

    # I have to use slice because the following command 
    #trace = pm.sample(5000)
    # produce the error 
    # ValueError: Cannot construct a ufunc with more than 32 operands 
    #(requested number were: inputs = 51 and outputs = 1)valueerror 


    xstart = pm.find_MAP()
    xstep = pm.Slice()
    trace = pm.sample(5000, xstep, xstart, random_seed = 123, progressbar= True)

pm.summary(trace)
```

I looked up the source code of glm and it seems that it uses vague priors as default 
and this practice is also recommended by Krutschke and many BUGS examples and it works (see above). 
However, stand reference manual (p.52) says that they *actively discourage users from using the default scale priors* because they *concentrate too much probability mass outside of reasonable posterior values (...) can have the profound effect of skewing posteriors*.

Comment: I guess you should use the Flat distribution.

Answer (score 4):

Uniform priors are defined in Stan on the support of a parameter.  So that if you declare a parameter `real<lower=0> sigma;` that declares `sigma` to have a uniform prior on positive values.  It does that by log-transforming `sigma` to (-inf, inf) and then accounting for the Jacobian;  I believe PyMC3 can do the same thing.   Stan allows improper priors if the posterior is proper.  Any other priors beyond the default uniform ones specified for a variable are multiplied in (added on the log scale), so they behave as expected (the default uniform distribution has no effect).

Having said that, we recommend in the Stan manual using at least weakly informative priors if not even stronger priors.  Check out the papers by Gelman cited in the regression section's discussion of priors to see how priors can get skewed.  And it's not just having priors that are too vague;  often uniform priors on a closed interval (as in many of the BUGS examples) will have a strong effect on the posterior --- you can visualize this in terms of the truncated likelihood function.  All of these can cause computational problems depending on the model's posterior geometry (and not just for HMC --- also for Gibbs or Metropolis).

The Gelman and Hill regression book examples (ARM) that we have on GitHub are not up to Stan's current modeling standards---they were just directly translated from the ARM code.  Revising all of those is on our to-do list for 2016 (along with the BUGS examples).  Some of the ARM examples are translated from examples in the book for R's `lm()` or `glm()` functions and some into the `lme4` package's `lmer()` and `glmer()` functions, none of which accept priors.  We're about to release the RStanARM package, which will accept R's regression (and lme4's multilevel regression) notation and allow either MLE (with error) or HMC estimates (with highly optimized model code on the back end).